# Download file from a url

Tags: powershell

I have a set of URLs using which I need to download files which can be of any type. I tried to use below PowerShell script, but the problem with this script is that I need to mention the type of the file. e.g. in below example I had to specify the type as PDF. Is there a way I can download file of any type from a URL to a specified folder?

```
$Path = "D:\Downloads\test.pdf"

# below url turns into 'https://xyz.abc.com/efg/TempData/data/%7B5a8662ff-1cbf-4141-bc93-c2f65657%7D/G4068.pdf'
$Url = "http://xyz.abc.com/efg/url.asp?SessID=1904B8A0E7B358A45F5422BC751CB763666BAB2F6EE10098823DFC10BCA2051260D63DCC93C0D9E63"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

Write-Host "Downloading" $Path -ForegroundColor Green

$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the response headers to learn the file type, then adjust the file as necessary.

```
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method get
Switch ($data.Headers.'Content-Type'){
    "*pdf*" {$Data.content | Out-File MyOutfile.pdf}
    "*jpeg*" {$Data.content | Out-File MyOutfile.jpg}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, I do not have list of all the content types which I can use it in the switch case statement. There can be files which were generated through different lab instruments and their file type can be very weird. e.g. .eda, .sdax etc. Also, I would like the downloaded file to retain it's original name and not giving a new name to it. Do you think, there is a way to achieve this??

Comment: The BaseResponse property of the webrequest object may get you the information you need.

$data.BaseResponse
$data.BaseResponse.ResponseUri